# resample data each column together in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe named zz
zz columns name ['Ancolmekar','Cidurian','Dayeuhkolot','Hantap','Kertasari','Meteolembang','Sapan']

```
for col in zz.columns:
    df = pd.DataFrame(zz[col],index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-12-31 23:50:00', freq='10T'))

df.resample('1M').mean()
```

error : invalid syntax

i want to know the mean value by month in 10 minutes data interval. when i run this just sapan values appear with NaN. before, i have replace the NaN data 1 else 0.

```
Sapan
2017-01-31  NaN
2017-02-28  NaN
2017-03-31  NaN
2017-04-30  NaN
2017-05-31  NaN
2017-06-30  NaN
2017-07-31  NaN
2017-08-31  NaN
2017-09-30  NaN
2017-10-31  NaN
2017-11-30  NaN
2017-12-31  NaN
2018-01-31  NaN
2018-02-28  NaN
2018-03-31  NaN
2018-04-30  NaN
2018-05-31  NaN
2018-06-30  NaN
2018-07-31  NaN
2018-08-31  NaN
2018-09-30  NaN
2018-10-31  NaN
2018-11-30  NaN
2018-12-31  NaN
2019-01-31  NaN
2019-02-28  NaN
2019-03-31  NaN
2019-04-30  NaN
2019-05-31  NaN
2019-06-30  NaN
2019-07-31  NaN
2019-08-31  NaN
2019-09-30  NaN
2019-10-31  NaN
2019-11-30  NaN
2019-12-31  NaN
2020-01-31  NaN
2020-02-29  NaN
2020-03-31  NaN
2020-04-30  NaN
2020-05-31  NaN
2020-06-30  NaN
2020-07-31  NaN
2020-08-31  NaN
2020-09-30  NaN
2020-10-31  NaN
2020-11-30  NaN
2020-12-31  NaN
2021-01-31  NaN
2021-02-28  NaN
2021-03-31  NaN
2021-04-30  NaN
2021-05-31  NaN
2021-06-30  NaN
2021-07-31  NaN
2021-08-31  NaN
2021-09-30  NaN
2021-10-31  NaN
2021-11-30  NaN
2021-12-31  NaN
```

what should i do? thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-assigninig variable `df` to a dataframe with a single column during each pass through the for loop. The last column is `sapan`. Hence, only  this column is shown.

Additionally, you are setting the index on `df` that probably isn't the index in `zz`, therefore you get Not A Number `NaN` for non-existing values.

If the index in `zz` is corresponding to the one you are setting, this should work:

```
df = zz.copy()
df['new_column'] = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-12-31 23:50:00', freq='10T'))
df = df.set_index('new_column')
df.resample('1M').mean()
```